# return code misunderstanding

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int calsum(int x,int y,int z);

int main()
{
    while(1)
    {
        int a, b, c, sum;
        printf("Enter any3 numbers");
        scanf("%d%d%d", &a, &b, &c);
        sum = calsum(a, b, c);
        printf("sum=%d\n", sum);
    }
}

int calsum (int x, int y, int z)
{
    int d;
    d = x + y + z;
    if(d > 2)
        return d;
    else
        d = 1;
    return;
}
```

when I am giving input as `-1 1 0` my output should be `1` but it is giving `0`
why?
it is all about adding three numbers

Comment: If your input is -1 1 0 and you add those 3 numbers, that gives you 0, why should there be 1? Also you want to correct the return statement to look like return 1, instead of d=1; return ;

Comment: Undefined behaviour in your `return` statement.

Comment: make the last return statement to return d;

Comment: I removed the C++ tag since your program wouldn't even compile with a C++ compiler.

Comment: Enable compiler warnings (`-Wall` for `gcc`) and the compiler will tell you where your bug is.

Answer (score 5):

```
 int calsum (int x,int y,int z)
 {
   return ;
 }
```

Your function is declared and defined to return an `int`, but your return statement is expressionless. It's a language constraint violation.

The behavior of your program is undefined. Funny results is a possible outcome in this case.

Comment: but if (return d;) is typed in place of (return;) and return in place of (return d) then it works according to the code

Comment: @AnkitMathur - Undefined behavior doesn't mean "it won't work". It means the language specification isn't going to bother with defining what should happen. It may appear to work, it may not, it may even fry your hard-drive for all the C language cares.

Comment: according to a book return; code gives garbage value as we are not returning any specified value but here if d is coming less than 2 then also output is correct and equal to d thats the problem

Comment: @AnkitMathur - I don't know what book your'e talking about, but it's either oversimplifying or plain wrong. You violate a language constraint! Your program can behave however the compiler writers want and it's still a legal program, just not one you can rely on to do anything useful

Answer (score 0):

Update your calsum function as below. You are assigning d=1 in else part but not returning it.

```
 int calsum (int x,int y,int z){
     int d;
     d=x+y+z;
     if(d>2)
        return d;
     else
        return 1;
     }
```

Comment: I would say update it to `int calsum(int x, int y, int z) { return x + y + z; }`. The above code chokes me.

Comment: @Haris: For x=y=z=0, your code will return 0, however the requirement is to return 1 in this condition.